# Beautify PyQt GUIs and printing to GUI(textbrowser or some other widget)

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I've made a GUI for my application but I've to make it look professional. Currently, I think it's looking casual. Also, I want to print some outputs to the textbrowser widget. How should I do that?

I've tried making some changes to stylesheets of widgets, but the options available are not adequate.

My GUI looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QTextBrowser class provides a rich text browser with hypertext navigation. It opens a URL to display, not plain text.

Use something like a QPlainTextEdit, or a QTextEdit for doing this.

They have methods like appendText, or appendPlainText.

Alternatively, you could have a website and host your text there, but that seems overly complicated.